# Windows 7 OEM reinstallation disk on a larger drive does not complete. Is there a work-around?

Tags: windows-7, sony-vaio, oem, sysprep

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Window's can't be configured after a system restore](https://superuser.com/questions/414362/windows-cant-be-configured-after-a-system-restore)

The 320gb hard disk of my Sony Vaio crashed, and I asked Sony reinstallation disk, while buying a new Western Digital 500gb hard disk.

Sony told me the reinstallation disks could work, but there would be no actual guarantee thereof.

Now I ran the 6 installation DVDs, and the installer copied all the files to my hard-disk, and rebooted. At the first run, I got the following message `Setup is starting the services` (may be an approximate translation, the actual message in in French). Then after 3 seconds, an error message saying that Windows couldn't finish the setup, and that it will reboot.

Is it due to the disk size change? Is there a work-around I can use to finish my setup?

Note:

- My previous hard drive: Toshiba MK3265GSX (SATA 2.6 / ATA- 8)
- New hard drive: WD Scorpio Blue WDBABC5000ANC-ERSN (Serial ATA-300)

Comment: The size of the disk shouldn't matter.  If it did anything, it would cause activation to fail - not something like this.  Can you post the actual error message that appears, or the error code?

Comment: Here's a [picture](http://twitpic.com/9pl2fc) of my error message. It's in French, so translated it says: "Windows could complete the installation. To install Windows on this computer, run the installation program again" (in the MsgBox). And below, the text "The installation program is starting the services"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing Windows again, like the error message says to do.  It might be one of those weird, transitory errors that happens.

The "starting services" message sounds like the message that normally appears when Windows boots up, so it probably finished most of the installation, but something just went wrong or didn't get copied.

EDIT: I think [this](https://superuser.com/questions/414362/windows-cant-be-configured-after-a-system-restore) might be the answer to your current problem.  It makes perfect sense with the new HDD - try out the answer there.

Comment: Thanks, I just tried that, and realized that the first time after the installation a different error is in fact returned.

Windows just finished configuring the devices, and the next step was : "The installer is applying system parameters", when I received the MsgBox "Windows installer couldn't configure Windows for execution on this computer's hardware".

Comment: At the next reboot, I activated ntbtlog.txt, and notice that 2 drivers won't load:

 - `Did not load driver \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\vga.sys`
 - `Did not load driver \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\NDProxy.sys`

Comment: vga.sys is a video driver, NDProxy is a network driver.  Since you can see the screen, vga.sys probably isn't the problem.  Can you boot into Safe Mode (hold F8 at Windows boot)?  I'm not sure how far along you are in the installation process.  If that doesn't work, I might have to tap out - I'm pretty much stumped, I've never seen something like this before with a fresh install.

Comment: I also ran the Acronys Alignment tool, which didn't detect any misalignment. It was recommended by Western Digital as this is a cloned software.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try with Safe Mode. If it doesn't work, I'll try installing another complete version of Windows 7 Home Premium instead of this current OEM. Which means I'll also get to give Microsoft another 200 euros for a new product key...

Comment: I might have found the answer, see the link I posted in my edit above.  It may be the new hard driver after all.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Indeed, compatibility problems between the Sony bios and the advanced format HDD seem to be the culprit.

Comment: Glad I could help.  Would you vote up anything that helped you in the other thread and close this as a duplicate of the other question?

Comment: Glad my linked post could help!

Comment: Thanks ChimneyImp and @Moab . I've flagged the question as duplicate, but am unfortunately not entitled to vote up yet. I'll try to remember and vote up later, as you really helped me!